# Why can't my Catalyst application read my Template Toolkit files?

Tags: perl, catalyst, template-toolkit

I am trying to get the [`Catalyst`](http://catalystframework.org) framework to work using [`Template Toolkit`](http://template-toolkit.org), and I'm having issues with [`Template::Provider`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Template::Provider). I've isolated the issue to calls to `stat`. In `Template::Provider::_init`, calls to `stat` work correctly, however in other functions calls to stat return []. It seems like [`Template::Provider`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Template::Provider) is doing some weird caching stuff, but I can't quite figure out what. Anyone have any ideas?

**EDIT:** A bit more detail:

I'm trying to move from the Catalyst development server to Apache/mod_perl. I get a `Couldn't render template "file error - mytemplate.tt: not found"` error. Here is the debug dump of my config:

```
Config
do {
  my $a = {
    "Action::RenderView" => {
          ignore_classes => [
                              "DBIx::Class::ResultSource::Table",
                              "DBIx::Class::ResultSourceHandle",
                              "DateTime",
                            ],
          scrubber_func  => sub { "???" },
        },
    "Plugin::ConfigLoader" => {},
    home => "/home/myuser/pathtosite",
    name => "Stream",
    root => bless({
          dirs => ["", "home", "myuser", "pathtosite"],
          file_spec_class => undef,
          volume => "",
        }, "Path::Class::Dir"),
    static => {
          debug => 1,
          dirs => [],
          ignore_dirs => [],
          ignore_extensions => ["tmpl", "tt", "tt2", "html", "xhtml"],
          include_path => ['fix'],
          mime_types => {},
          mime_types_obj => bless({}, "MIME::Types"),
          no_logs => 1,
        },
  };
  $a->{static}{include_path}[0] = $a->{root};
  $a;
}
```

Pretty much the exact same issue that someone described here: http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/catalyst/users/14888

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your files are actually in the `/home/myuser/pathtosite` directory (and not a subdirectory), this seems like it could be a perimssion problem with the Catalyst process not being able to read the files there.  If you're running in an SELinux environment, it could also have to do with the security context (e.g., security context type `httpd_sys_content_t`).

Can you do some debugging to ensure that the files are visible from the Catalyst process in the first place, before it attempts to render the template?

Comment: Almost bound to be this, in fact - if you're using a system Apache process on Linux, rather than one run by your user, it'll probably be running as www_user and have no access to your files.  I find developing with a self-run process works better, but you'll need to configure it to a high port (1024+) because only root has access to low ports.

Comment: Thanks guys--this was indeed the correct answer. It was a permission issue. Tip for anyone who reads this in the future: try using strace is very helpful for debugging these kinds of things. It shows systems calls that a process makes, and in my case it showed the file apache was trying to open along with the permission denied error. (`sudo strace httpd 2>&1 | grep hello.tt` did the trick)